# Append a single character to a string or char array in java?

Tags: java, string, append

Is it possible to append a single character to the end of `array` or `string` in java. Example:

```
private static void /*methodName*/ () {            
    String character = "a"
    String otherString = "helen";
    //this is where i need help, i would like to make the otherString become 
    // helena, is there a way to do this?               
}
```

Comment: i have tried the append method but i am very confused about how to use it...

Comment: So *how* have you tried to use the append method? And have you tried simple string concatenation via +? Note that strings and arrays are entirely different things...

Comment: @CodeLover.. Did you check the documentation of `String` class. It does not have any `append` method. Google for `String Concatenation in Java`. May be you can get some idea

Comment: Sinnce they are string you can use the builtin string concatenation mechanism of the language by doing `otherString + character` here.

Comment: You are thinking of the `StringBuilder` class with the append method.

Comment: yes i forgot about using += as the others detailed below so that is how i will do it

Comment: Show more research effort. Don't post a question here every time you forget something/want to know some basic operation/method.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

```
1. String otherString = "helen" + character;

2. otherString +=  character;
```

Answer (score 11):

You'll want to use the static method Character.toString(char c) to convert the character into a string first. Then you can use the normal string concatenation functions.

Answer (score 9):

```
new StringBuilder().append(str.charAt(0))
                   .append(str.charAt(10))
                   .append(str.charAt(20))
                   .append(str.charAt(30))
                   .toString();
```

This way you can get the new string with whatever characters you want.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you use here two strings: "" marks a string it may be `""`-empty `"s"`- string of lenght 1 or  `"aaa"` string of lenght 3, while '' marks chars .  In order to be able to do `String str = "a" + "aaa" + 'a'` you must use  method Character.toString(char c) as @Thomas Keene said so an example would be `String str = "a" + "aaa" + Character.toString('a')`

Answer (score 3):

And for those who are looking for when you have to concatenate a char to a String rather than a String to another String as given below.

```
char ch = 'a';
String otherstring = "helen";
// do this
otherstring = otherstring + "" + ch;
System.out.println(otherstring);
// output : helena
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'd advise reviewing how this works in Java. The accepted answer works regardless of whether the variable named character is a 'char' or a 'String' and the empty String in your answer: [otherstring + "" + ch] is unnecessary. Also, I do not think that this question requires another new answer as the existing answers provide sufficient coverage.

Comment: I answered this question because if you look closely, you will find out that the question title is a little vague and is not related to the question which user intended to ask and I tried to answer exactly that. cheers!!

Comment: The need of adding an empty. "" in the line otherstring = otherstring + "" + ch;
is totally useless.

Answer (score 2):

just add them like this :

```
        String character = "a";
        String otherString = "helen";
        otherString=otherString+character;
        System.out.println(otherString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class lab {
public static void main(String args[]){
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter a string:");
   String s1;
   s1 = input.nextLine();
   int k = s1.length();
   char s2;
   s2=s1.charAt(k-1);
   s1=s2+s1+s2;
   System.out.println("The new string is\n" +s1);
   }
  }
```

Here's the output you'll get.

*
Enter a string
     CAT
The new string is
     TCATT
*

It prints the the last character of the string to the first and last place. You can do it with any character of the String.