# How do I add a character to the beginning and end of a String?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

```
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Hi, I have this while loop. This output variable is a String variable and it's keeping the output from `br.readLine())`.

Let's say `br.readLine())` is giving 2 lines.

So `System.out.println(output);` is printing those lines as:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
```

Can somebody tell me how to add a `{` at the begining of the first line and at the end of the last line? Like this:

```
{AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD}
```

I tried this by doing something like this:

```
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("{"+output+"}");
}
```

This added a bracket after each line.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder` and a `StringJoiner`

Comment: You want to especially look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40020825/1531124 from the duplicated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try something like:

```
String line = "";
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  output += line;
}

output = "{" + output + "}";
```

Update:

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("{");
String line = "";
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  output.append(line);
}
output.append("}");
```

Comment: output = "{" + output + "}"; This is null

Comment: Please check the updated version ...

Comment: This worked ! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution I see, print the opening character before your loop and the closing character after. Like,

```
System.out.print("{");
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(output);
}
System.out.println("}");
```

Comment: No. Can't do like this because i want to store everything in output variable.

Comment: @Manu And MadProgrammer suggested you to use a StringBuilder/Joiner 15 minutes ago. That is exactly what you need here.

Comment: @Manu Or write to a different `PrintStream` (you could wrap a `ByteArrayOutputStream`).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String readData(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    buf.append('{');

    String output;

    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (buf.length() > 1)
            buf.append('\n');
        buf.append(output);
    }

    return buf.append('}').toString();
}
```