# How to add a char into an array using add?

Tags: java

I am trying to coding Java and adding a char to an array. My idea is compare two char, if they are different, I will add them to an array and here is my code.

```
ArrayList<String> different = new ArrayList<>();
if (character.charAt(i) == (character.charAt(i+1))) 
{
}
else
{
    different.add(character.charAt(i+1));
}
```

But when I run my code, they said to me that "no suitable method found for add (char)" at line 6, and I can not run the code. Could you please give me some ideas? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: seems duplicate of this:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444717/append-a-single-character-to-a-string-or-char-array-in-java/14444748

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append a single character to a string or char array in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444717/append-a-single-character-to-a-string-or-char-array-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are adding char datatype to an arraylist which is of type String. You need to change the code to:

```java
ArrayList<Character> different = new ArrayList<>();
if (character.charAt(i) != (character.charAt(i + 1))) {
    different.add(character.charAt(i + 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`String::charAt` returns a `char`, not a `String`. So your `char` cannot be put into a list holding `String` objects. Square peg, round hole.

Also `char` is a legacy type, limited to a subset of less than half of the over 110,000 characters defined in Unicode, restricted to code points in the  “basic plane”. You should learn to work with code points as numbers to be able to handle any Unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

When you declared `List<String>` or `ArrayList<String>`, it means the List should contain type `String` or literals(something between double quote `""`. FYI, this is called Generic Type.

Use `String#valueOf(char c)` to create new `String` from a `char`. Example:-

```
//returns a type char
char c = character.charAt(i+1);

//use String#valueOf(char c) to create new `String` from variable `c`
different.add(String.valueOf(c));
```

** Oracle has good tutorial on Generic Type, you could refer to it.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList<Character> different = new ArrayList<>();`

`if (character.charAt(i) == (character.charAt(i+1))) 
{
}
else
{
different.add(character.charAt(i+1));
}`

///////////////////

Just add Wrapper class Character instead of String.